# Change API response in the middle of a test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I want to test a component that shows a loading screen and then when the API sends the data, it shows the data accordingly.

I know how to do this in different test suites, but I want to do it in the same test — the API might change additional data over time and I want to test the component going from one state to the other.

For context, I'm using `useSWR`, but I mock the entire hook that calls it (as seen below).

The file below explains it as well:

- First, I import and mock the hook
- Then, I render the component (with the default mocked value) and assert that the loading is there.
- I change the response of this mock hook to something different
- The second assertion group should pass but it doesn't. The mock isn't even called again (I `console`'d it).

```
import { useCustomHook } from "./useCustomHook"

jest.mock(
  "useCustomHook",
  () => ({
    useCustomHook: jest.fn(() => ({
      isLoading: true,
      response: undefined,
    })),
  }),
)
const mockuseCustomHook = useCustomHook as jest.Mock

describe("Component", () => {
  it('Should render properly', () => {
    render(<Component />)

    expect(screen.getByText('Loading')).toBeInTheDocument()

    mockuseCustomHook.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
      isLoading: false,
      response: { data: 'This is the data' },
    }))

    expect(screen.queryByText('Loading')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText('This is the data')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Comment: The hook doesn't get called again unless the component re-renders.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so I'd need to call `rerender`? But doesn't that fail the purpose of the test (the component automatically rerendering when the API response changes)?

Comment: _"the component automatically rerendering when the API response changes"_ is a slightly faulty model of what's happening. I'd guess your real hook is using e.g. `useState` under the hood: it's the state update that triggers the re-render, then when the component function is called it calls the hook again and gets the new data. With your test double there's no trigger at all for the rerender.